# Убрать дубликаты из строки в цикле php foreach

Tags: php, строки, циклы

Есть `string`-поле вида:

```
ТестТестТестТестТестПроверкаПроверкаПроверка
```

Как убрать дубликаты и на выходе получить вид:

```
ТестПроверка
```

Comment: А код где, который формирует эту строку с дублями, раз речь про цикл идет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

[array-unique](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) подойдет ?

```
$input = [ 'Тест', 'Тест', 'Тест', 'Тест', 'Тест', 'Проверка', 'Проверка', 'Проверка' ];

$result = array_unique( $input );
print_r( $result );
```

Саму строку можно разбить с помощью [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$string  = "ТестТестТестТестТестПроверкаПроверкаПроверка" ; 

preg_match_all('/([А-Я][а-я]+)\1+/u', $string, $m);
echo implode('', $m[1]); // ТестПроверка
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно следующий алгоритм получается:

```
$s = "TestTestTestTestTestControlControlControl";
$tokens = array();  // Сюда помещаем найденные токены
do {
   // Начинаем поиск очередного токена
   $sub = "";
   $i = 0;
   $tokenFound = false;
   do {
      // Добавляем к токену очередной символ и ищем повторы
      $sub = $sub . s[$i];
      ++$i;
      $pos = strpos($s, $sub, $i);
      $len = strlen($sub);
      if ($pos == false) {
         // Если повторы не найдены, значит мы нашли уникальный токен
         $tokenFound = true;
         array_push($tokens, $sub);
         $s = substr($s, $len);
      }
      // Продолжаем формирование токена, пока не дойдём до его первого повтора
   } while ((! $tokenFound) && ($pos != $len));
   if (!$tokenFound) {
      // Если повторы были, значит токен сформирован, удаляем повторы
      array_push($tokens, $sub);
      while (strpos($s, $sub) == 0) {
         $s = substr($s, $len);
      }
   }
   // Продолжаем поиск, пока в строке остаются символы
} while(strlen($s));
// Склеиваем найденные токены в одну строку
$result = implode($tokens);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вхоные данные немного модифицировать вариант splash58 будет не корректно работать, лучше так

```
$string  = "ТестТестПроверкаТестТестТестПроверкаПроверкаПроверка" ;
preg_match_all('/[А-Я]{1}[а-я]+/u', $string, $m);
echo implode('', array_unique($m[0]));
```